# NHibernate Mapping Issue (I think)

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Ok, so I have an object named "Business" (I know, I know, "Business Business Object")
When it saved its foreign keys are getting lost somehow. Everything else is saving. I have stepped through the code and followed the object up until the

session.SaveOrUpdate(businessObject);

method. The object at that point is intact and the foreign properties seem to be there. However when it is saved the foreign IDs are not in the Business Table. I can only imagine this may be due to me not mapping them correctly?

Here is where they are being mapped:

```
<many-to-one insert="false" update="false" name="_Township" column="TownshipId" class="HQData.Objects.Township, HQData" />

    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" name="_User" column="UserId" class="HQData.Objects.User, HQData" />

    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" name ="_SubCategory" column="SubCategoryId" class="HQData.Objects.SubCategory, HQData"/>
```

Here is where the object is being loaded and saved:

```
HQData.Objects.Business business = null;
            if (BusinessId != 0)
                business = BusinessManager.GetBusiness(BusinessId);
            else
                business = new HQData.Objects.Business();
            business._SubCategory = CategoryManager.GetCategory(Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategory.SelectedValue.Trim()));
            business.Name = ControlHelper.Sanitize(txtName.Text.Trim());
            business.Address1 = ControlHelper.Sanitize(txtAddress.Text.Trim());
            business._Township = TownshipManager.GetTownshipByCityorZip(ControlHelper.Sanitize(txtTownship.Text));
            business.PhoneNumber = ControlHelper.Sanitize(txtPhone.Text.Trim());
            business.FaxNumber = ControlHelper.Sanitize(txtFax.Text.Trim());
            business.Email = ControlHelper.Sanitize(txtEmail.Text.Trim());
            business.Website = ControlHelper.Sanitize(txtWebsite.Text.Trim());
            business.AboutUs = ControlHelper.Sanitize(txtAboutUs.Text.Trim());
            business._User = UserManager.GetCurrentUser();


            BusinessManager.SaveBusiness(business);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the insert update properties to true or remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean business._SubCategory.SubCategoryId

and not sure what GetCurrentUser returns but if Id as well...

business._User.UserId?

Comment: the object gets mapped in the Business.cs file as:

        public virtual User _User
        { get; set; }

so, I don't think I can set the ID value, I set the entire object, no?

Comment: Yes, it just looks like you are setting an int to the SubCategory instead of a SubCategory object.  Don't set the Id value, instead set the SubCategory to the object.

Comment: Crap nevermind, just saw the CategoryManager.GetCategory around the int stuff.   Oops.